# Lumen 5.2 PDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections

Tags: database, laravel-5, lumen

When running my PHPUnit tests, I get the following error

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[08004] [1040] Too many connections`

I am running a lot of tests, but I am afraid this could happen in a not-test situation as well.

My tests are doing guzzle requests to my Lumen 5.2 API. The Lumen API basically gets a request and checks the oAuth token (connecting to the oAuth DB). If it is correct it connects to a different database (this is done by setting the `$connection` variable in the `Model`) and uses the `Model` to retrieve data.

Is the model not closing the connection?
Any idea? Is there any information I should provide, to help solve this problem?

Comment: Is it possible that you have some transactions that you don't commit?

Comment: I think it was actually due to PHPUnit being one huge script. Apparently Laravel/Lumen disconnects when the script finishes, but all testscases seem to count as one script.

Adding `\DB::disconnect();` in the `tearDown` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was actually due to PHPUnit being one huge script. Apparently Laravel/Lumen disconnects when the script finishes, but all testscases seem to count as one script. Adding \DB::disconnect(); in the tearDown solved my issue.